# Autofit table view cell in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm struggling to find correct iOS7 implementations.

I have a tableview that is populated by an array that retrieves JSON data from my server. This data could be any length. Right now I can only get it to 1 or 2 lines, nothing more.

Does anyone have any tips on the correct `heightForRowAtIndexPath` implementation?

Thanks

EDIT (current code):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
// Retrieve the line for this index (from JSON)

NSString *line = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

size = [line boundingRectWithSize: (CGSize){640, CGFLOAT_MAX} options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                             attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]} context: nil].size;
return ceilf(size.height);
}
```

Comment: Currently this is my code: `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // Retrieve the line for this index (from JSON)
    
    NSString *line = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

    size = [line boundingRectWithSize: (CGSize){640, CGFLOAT_MAX} options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                 attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]} context: nil].size;
    return ceilf(size.height);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` properly, something like this

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // Retrieve the line for this index (from JSON)
    NSString* line = ...

    // Measure it with UIKit
    // font is a UIFont* and should be prepared once when the view initialized
    // cellSize is a CGSize like (320, 10000), where 320 is the width of the cell, 10000 means we want it as high as needed
    CGSize sz = [line sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:cellSize lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return sz.height;
}
```

For `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, simply make the label fit the whole cell.

For more info on NSString UIKit Additions, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3acontext%3a). Note that the method `[sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]` is deprecated in iOS 7, and has been replaced by another one, but I am not sure how to use it :)